# To the YEC, did God make a single male/female pair of each kind of animal?

Tags: genesis, creation, young-earth-creation, literalism

Genesis 1:21-22

> So God created the great creatures of the sea and every living thing
>   with which the water teems and that moves about in it, according to
>   their kinds, and every winged bird according to its kind. And God saw
>   that it was good
>
> God blessed them and said, "Be fruitful and increase in number and
>   fill the water in the seas, and let the birds increase on the earth."

Genesis 1:24

> And God said, "Let the land produce living creatures according to
>   their kinds: the livestock, the creatures that move along the ground,
>   and the wild animals, each according to its kind." And it was so.

For example :
A. God create a bunch of elephants, cows, doves, eagles, penguins, dolphins, dogs, ants, snakes, etc etc ... here and there across the earth - male and female.

B. God create 2 elephants, 2 cows, 2 doves, 2 eagles, 2 penguins, 2 dolphins, 2 ants, 2 snakes, etc etc ... male and female for each type and they are all in one place ---> Something like when on the 6th day we go to a zoo or to an African Safari, many types of animal are there - but there are only two for each type, male and female.

C. Almost like B, but the two elephants on the most North of the earth, the two doves somewhere on other part of the earth, the two penguins on the most South of the earth, **the two snakes exactly in the Eden Garden**, etc etc. In other words, the size of the "African Safari" is as big as the earth size :).

So, according to the YEC - is it A or B or C ?

Thank you.

Comment: This is an interesting question which could have a more interesting follow-up.

Comment: Could you clarify C?

Comment: @Sola I think in (b) All the pairs are created in the Garden and have to migrate to their habitats.  In (c) the pairs are created in their natural habitats. Only a small portion of created pairs are in the Garden.

Comment: I'm curious. What use will you put this information to? I'm sure it will help with slanting the answer, if any.

Comment: Yes bradimus, in (b) the pair of each type are in a smaller area (more concentrate because the area is smaller), while in (c) the pair of each type are spread to any part of the world. For illustration of (b) : in a 1000 m2 land size there are 2 dogs, 2 elephants, 2 snakes, 2 dolphins, 2 ants, and so on until, say there are 5000 types of animal. One does not need much time to find those 5000 types of animal in a 1000m2 land size. (continue)

Comment: Illustration of (c) : one need more time because he/she needs to travel the whole earth to finally find those 5000 type of animal. Adam and Eve maybe never see a "husband & wife" dinosaurus because this dinosaurus couple is somewhere of the part of the earth which is so far away from where Adam and Eve live.

Comment: @Steve, I would like to know the detail. If the answer _"We don't know. Maybe it's A, maybe it's B, maybe it's C"_ then A / B / C is possible. Assume it's A, then [God created mankind in his own image, in the image of God he created them; male and female he created them] is not only two but a bunch of male and female human here and there  across the earth is possible. (continue)

Comment: Then [Cain meet strangers with no blood relation in the Land of Nod] is possible. Then _"whoever finds me will kill me"_ it's not because this "whoever" want to take revenge knowing Cain killed Abel but because Cain is a stranger to this "whoever".

Comment: Does Genesis 2:19 answer your question? Adam named all the creatures that God brought him.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with specific YEC beliefs, but I think they believe in either A or B. C is unlikely (though not impossible), because God would have had to let Adam name the animal and then miraculously relocate the animal to someplace on the earth. YEC's do believe, however, that Adam and Eve are the only first 2 humans (see Genesis 3:20).

Comment: @Steve, I am sorry .... Gen 2:19 does not answer my question.

Comment: @4castle, the (A) condition on the 6th day : there are male and female which today we call it Cobra snakes in Eden in 200 meters radius... BUT there are also other males and females Cobra outside that 200 meters radius, say 1000 km radius... and there is also more males and females Cobra outside that 1000 km radius (say in the area which we call today Amazon jungle, African jungle, Asia, China, etc). Thank you.

Comment: Why are you limiting God, to your concepts. God spoke everything into existence , so what difference does it make whether he said make thousands of this, or make two of this? We humans all too often limit God to our parameters, while God has no parameters. It is almost impossible for our minds to comprehend being totally unlimited. God is.

Comment: @bye there might be a different view. As my post before - there might be a possibilities that a view which holds [God wanted that incest must be done in that time] is not fit anymore because Gen 1:27 is not only two people if the answer to this question is A.

Comment: adding possible variables only diminishes God; in that it intimates that God in light of better options, chose a lesser method. For myself it is an exercise in futility to second guess God.

Comment: @BYE, do you mean that [God wanted that incest must be done in that time] is not a guess from the readers ? Wouldn't not allowing a possibility is actually restricting God ? --->  _Because **we think** there is only Adam's family then God must have wanted incest to be done between them_.

Comment: NO! what I mean is that GOD IS SUPREME, as his creation we do not have the authority to judge his actions by our perceived morals. God knows what he is doing even if we are not as intelligent as he is. After all Adam married his rib! WE might have a rough go at applying our moralistic code to that one.

Comment: [we do not have the authority to judge his actions by our perceived morals] ---> Do we "judge" God based on what we don't know before which we know it later ? For illustration, (1) Before God say _"Honor your father and mother"_ , is it OK for God if human not honor their parents ? (2) Before God say _"Cursed is anyone who sleeps with his father's wife - Cursed is anyone who sleeps with his sister"_, anybody who have sex with his mother and sister is not cursed ? Your answer to both question I think will be : Yes ! :).

Answer (score 4):

**The Answer is A.**  The question is very good, but a lot of people are not familiar with the phrase - YEC [It should be explained ] and it also should be noted that many who hold this view do not use or like this term - Young Earth Creationists, because something that is 6-10 thousand years is ancient - not young. It's better to use the term Biblical Creationists, or "those who believe in the literal creation account".
The creation account in Genesis 1:20-24 doesn't say explicitly, but when we look at other passages, [using solid principles of Bible Interpretation- scripture interprets scripture, and other clear passages inform or shed light on less clear ones] we can see that the **answer is A.**
It is a common view among those Biblical Creationists- who hold the literal creation position - that the original earth was one giant land mass and split as a result of plate tectonics in the Genesis flood.  We know this from at least 2 separate scriptures, and it's important to the topic.  I Chronicles 1:19 and Genesis 10:25 "In the days of Peleg, the earth was divided."
https://answersingenesis.org/geology/plate-tectonics/did-the-continents-split-apart-in-the-days-of-peleg/.
So in this scenario there were thousands of miles of continuous, connected land mass.  If God had only made 2 otters or 2 racc0ons, or 2 rabbits, or 2 squirrels, they could have been devoured in the first week by a vulture, fox or eagle and poof, 1/3 of the animals are extinct in a year.
But this leads us to the other evidence from scripture. *Remember that we should compare scripture to help shed light on questions like these and other issues.

Ask most of your Christian friends "How many of each kind of animal were on the ark"? and they will immediately say two. But this is a commonly held myth.
It's great for helping 4 year old kids remember the story, and making kids songs rhyme, but it's not true.
Scripture explicitly says that there were 2 of the unclean animals but 7 pairs of the birds and 7 pairs of clean animals. It's no coincidence that the sacrificial animals are also the same animals they could eat.
Genesis 7:1-3 "Then the LORD said to Noah, “Go into the ark, you and all your household, for I have seen that you are righteous before me in this generation. 2 Take with you **seven pairs of all clean animals**,a the male and his mate, and a pair of the animals that are not clean, the male and his mate, 3 **and seven pairs of the birds** of the heavens also, male and female, to keep their offspring alive on the face of all the earth.
As soon as Noah and his family left the ark, they made a sacrifice, so if there were 2, then the sheep and goats would immediately be extinct.

It's clear from other scripture that the pure spotless young lamb was to be a perfect picture of his son- the spotless lamb of God, so it wouldn't work for God to have people sacrifice unclean animals - and the other point is that scripture says that it is slothful to kill an animal and not eat it.
God's design of clean animals for sacrifice and for eating also provided a means for the Old Testament priests to eat.

Comment: +1 for referencing "runaway subduction"!

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I'm surprised that on a forum like this, that people give answers and actually cite the " 2 by 2 animals on the ark Myth" and people give that a vote up.  Heheh.

Comment: "_As soon as Noah and his family left the ark, they made a sacrifice, so if there were 2, then the sheep and goats would immediately be extinct._". Very nice logic. So, it more likely the answer is A.

Answer (score -2):

**Variant A**.

Saint Ephrem the Syrian (306 – 373) writes in "[Commentary on Genesis](http://www.trueorthodoxy.info/pat_stephraim_commentary_genesis.shtml)":

> After Moses spoke about the lights that came to be in the firmament, he turned to write about the swarming things, the birds and the serpents that were created from the waters on the fifth day, saying, "And God said, 'Let the waters cause living things to swarm, and let the birds fly above the earth.' And God created the great serpents and every living creature with which the waters swarmed according to their kind." (Gen 1:20, 1:21)
>
> When the waters were gathered, which had been ordered on the second day, the rivers were ordered and also springs, lakes, and ponds were revealed. *At the word of God, these waters--dispersed throughout creation--brought forth swarming things and fish from within them: the serpents were created within the abysses and the birds soared in flocks out of the waves into the air.*
>
> ... After Moses spoke about the creation of the swarming things and of the birds and the sea serpents on the fifth day, he turned to write about the creeping things and the animals and the beasts that were created on the sixth day, saying, "And God said, 'Let the earth bring forth living creatures according to their kinds: cattle and reptiles and beasts.'" ( Gen 1:24) *Although the entire earth was swarming with swarming things, nevertheless the cattle and the beasts were made on the border of Paradise* so that they might dwell at the appointed place of Adam.
>
> Then the entire earth stirred with creeping things as it had been commanded. The earth also brought forth the beasts of the field as companions to the wild beasts, and it brought forth as many beasts as would be useful for the service of that one who, on that very day, was to transgress the commandment of his Lord.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking in the context of the modern YEC movement. If that is case, this answer would benefit from the addition of sources indicating that the YEC accept Ephraim's teachings.

Comment: Saint Ephrem the Syrian is one of the most famous and authoritative Fathers of the Church and interpreters of the Word of God like saint John Chrysostom, saint Basil the Great , saint Gregory the Theologian or  saint Athanasius the Great. Word of God and Fathers of the Church, not only modern YEC movement, teach us the truth that God created the universe in six days (in sense Earth's rotation period).

Comment: @DenisMath, [Although the entire earth was swarming with swarming things, nevertheless the cattle and the beasts were made on the border of Paradise] ---> It seems St. Ephrem was talking about Gen 2:19 ? Please CMIIW (correct me if I'm wrong). Thank you.

Comment: @bradimus, you are right that at least there is a source indicating the YEC today accept Ephrem's teaching about this. Because this question, depends on the answer - it may make another question based on the answer. So if Ephrem's answer/teaching is option(A) but the today's YEC teaching is not option(A) then it will be difficult for me to make another question. Thank you.

Comment: @karma The quotation from Genesis 1:24 before the selected text of St. Ephraim shows what he interprets: "And God said, 'Let the earth bring forth living creatures according to their kinds: cattle and reptiles and beasts.'" (Gen 1:24) Although the entire earth was swarming with swarming things, nevertheless the cattle and the beasts were made on the border of Paradise..."

Comment: @karma According to the interpretation of St. Ephraim, the naming of animals (Genesis 2:19) occurred on the same sixth day of the creation of the universe, when animals, Adam and Eva were created.

Comment: @karma Moreover, the fall of Adam and Eve occurred on the same sixth day, when they were created: "The entire reason the serpent was not prevented from coming hastily was because the serpent's very haste worked against the serpent. For it was the moment that Eve had been created, and she did not yet know what hunger was; and up to now she had not been tormented by any struggle over the Tree's beauty. So, because she was not hungry and was not struggling with the Tree, the serpent was not prevented from becoming a tempter."

Comment: @DenisMath, [Although the entire earth was swarming with swarming things, nevertheless the cattle and the beasts were made on the border of Paradise] ---> I am sorry I don't understand what did he mean with "swarming things". Did he mean (Gen 1:20) animals which live in the water and also animals which fly ? ---> assume my guessing is correct, then something like this : [Although the plesiosaurs, dolphins, crocodiles, Pterosaurs, doves, eagles, bees, butterflies, etc etc are swarming the entire earth --- but the T-rex, cows, dogs, lions, tigers, etc begin to exist only on the border of Eden.

Comment: [the naming of animals (Genesis 2:19)] --->what I mean is not about the naming of the animals, Denis. From what I read in Gen 2.... At first Adam is alone in the Eden. Then God think that it's not good Adam that Adam is alone. Then God made him a helper ---> So the LORD God formed from the ground all the wild animals and all the birds of the sky (Gen 2:19). That's what I mean, DenisMath. Thank you.

Comment: For your third comment, I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean. But it's OK because it's not about what I want to know in this question. Thank you DenisMath.

Comment: @karma "I don't understand what did he mean with "swarming things". Did he mean (Gen 1:20) animals which live in the water and also animals which fly?"  Oh sure! "Swarming things" are  all animals, "living creatures" (Gen 1:20), that were created in waters around the globe in the fifth day.

Comment: @karma "God think that it's not good Adam that Adam is alone. Then God made him a helper ---> So the LORD God formed from the ground all the wild animals and all the birds of the sky" No no, Adam was created AFTER the creation of every kind of living beings. In God's words "It is not good that man should be alone" (Gen 2:18) "alone" means without "helper comparable to him", a being of the same essence as Adam, i.e. human, not helper as a bull or horse.

Comment: @DenisMath, Gen 2:18 _[the LORD God said, "It is not good for the man to be alone. I will make a helper who is just right for him."
]_. I thought the literal chronology from the sentence is something like this : Adam is alone, there is no helper for him that time .... it seems both Adam himself found himself alone without helper and God himself see that Adam has no helper . That's why God say _"It is not good for the man to be alone. **I will make** a helper suitable for him."_  . (continue)

Comment: So... after [I will make] ---> then _[the LORD God formed from the ground all the wild animals and all the birds of the sky]_ ---> after all the wild animals and birds of the sky existed ---> then [He brought them to the man to see what he would call them, and the man chose a name for each one.] The sequence from Gen 2:18-19 : Adam exist first, alone... then the animals intended for Adam's helper.

Comment: [means without "helper comparable to him", a being of the same essence as Adam, **i.e. human**] --->I think this is the readers thought, not Adam :). For Adam, the animals which God JUST formed from the ground intended for Adam's helper, he thinks there is none of them suitable for him ---> Gen 2:20 [The man gave names to all livestock and to the birds of the heavens and to every beast of the field. **But for Adam there was not found a helper fit for him**].

Comment: Saying that when God say "a helper" ---> He means a human helper not the animals He formed from the ground, then I think the Literalist ignoring verse 19 and 20. From verse 18, skip verse 19 and 20 and jump directly to verse 21 ----> (18) the LORD God said, “It is not good that the man should be alone; I will make him a helper fit for him. (21) So the LORD God caused a deep sleep to fall upon the man, and while he slept took one of his ribs and closed up its place with flesh. Would you please explain, Denis ? Thank you.

Comment: Since this question asks for a YEC perspective, why wouldn't the perspective of any YEC adherant qualify for an answer. Asking for a citation from a YEC publication would have no more authority as my answer, assuming this question is even under discussion. If it were I am confident they would come to the same conclusion as I did.

Answer (score -2):

Genesis 1:21-22

> So God created the great creatures of the sea and every living thing
>   with which the water teems and that moves about in it, according to
>   their kinds, and every winged bird according to its kind. And God saw
>   that it was good God blessed them and said, "Be fruitful and increase
>   in number and fill the water in the seas, and let the birds increase
>   on the earth.

In this verse it doesn't clarify how many he made.

Genesis 1:24

> And God said, "Let the land produce living creatures according to
>   their kinds: the livestock, the creatures that move along the ground,
>   and the wild animals, each according to its kind." And it was so.

This verse doesn't say either. This calls for some in depth research...

Genesis 6:20

> Of the birds after their kind, of animals after their kind, and of
>   every creeping thing of the earth after its kind, two of every kind
>   will come to you to keep them alive.

God only put two of each animal on the ark. This hints that God only needed two of each kind to be created. It's not specific on where they were created, but God said to fill the Earth. I would say B is correct because God would have created them for Adam and Eve to see. And if the theory of Pangea is correct, God would have only created them in one spot, since Pangea is one continent.

Sites visited:
https://answersingenesis.org/kids/noahs-ark/how-did-noah-get-two-of-every-sea-animal-on-the-ark/

Comment: I like the logic based on the Noah's ark story. So if I'm a literalist, yes I think the answer is B. Also it can be seen that after the flood, then all those each pair of any kind of animals are in one spot. Thank you Joel for your answer.

Comment: Off topic, if you are interested - I have some other questions which similar about Genesis and can be "inter-connected". Maybe you would like to answer that other questions. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any references of YECs actually making this argument?

Comment: Myself. I'm a YEC

Comment: Joel, you've cited a very common myth in Christianity regarding Noah's flood and the ark. You should re-read the story again.  The notion of 2 by 2 was to make a nice rhyme for Children's songs - but the truth is that there were 7 pairs of the clean animals. So 14 cows, - 14 goats, 14 sheep, but 2 camels, 2 elephants.

Comment: Genesis 7:1-3 says that there were 7 pairs of clean animals and also 7 pairs of birds.  If God had only made 2 rabbits and 2 chipmunks and 2 squirrels, then an eagle or hawk would have eaten them on the first day - making all rabbits extinct in one week.

Comment: @tennman7, your explanation is very interesting. Based on point-B answer, even if people say : _no animal eat animal before the fall_, but then after the fall, the lion eat animals, then there will be some animals extinct (because the husband or the wife of the animal is eaten by the lion).